# Azure Active Directory: 'Forbidden' error while fetching groupclaims using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm using Azure Active Directory tenant along with Graph API to fetch groupclaims objectIDs. 
However, it's failing with Forbidden error at runtime.

I used the same code with another Azure Active Directory tenant (which created almost 4 months back), it's working perfectly. 
I have followed ditto to create new Azure Active Direct tenant and double checked configuration details in Azure management portal.

Even, I have created many times new [Azure Active Directory](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims) tenant with the same steps but still getting a Forbidden error.

```
{
    StatusCode: 403,
    ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden',
    Version: 1.1,
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
    Headers: {
        ocp-aad-diagnostics-server-name: a***********Bc=
        request-id: 9*******1
        client-request-id: 4b**************b9
        x-ms-dirapi-data-contract-version: 1.5
        x-ms-gateway-rewrite: false
        ocp-aad-session-key: GXB**********************5bi0
        X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
        DataServiceVersion: 3.0;
        Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
        Duration: 1168232
        Cache-Control: private
        Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
        X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
        X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
        X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
        Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 23:29:43 GMT
        Content-Length: 139
        Content-Type: application/json; odata=minimalmetadata; streaming=true; charset=utf-8
    }
}
```

In general, Forbidden error is due to lack of permissions on the server, but another active directory tenant is working perfectly (which is also created by me 4 months back). There isn’t any configuration change between the working AAD Tenant and newly created one.

1. Is there any recent changes in AAD creation?
2. I’m using Microsoft Active Directory, do we need any configuration update from MSIT team on server side?

followed the steps: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims

Could someone help me to fix this issue.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSIT team owns server side configuration setting. 
Contacting them has been fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure groupclaims that you try to access is in azure subscription you have access, also try creating new groupclaim and try to fetch using GraphAPi

Comment: Thanks for the comment. 


First, I'm using Microsoft Active Directory and trying to pull login user groupclaims objectIDs through Graph API. 

That means, whoever login to our site, we will pull that user all groupclaims objectIDs from Microsoft Directory through Graph API then validated. 

In perfect scenario, we should be able to fetch groupclaim objectIDs for login user. 
However, I’m still getting forbidden error while retrieving the groupclaims.